# Communication between two Android app on two different phones

Tags: android, sockets, communication, p2p

I want to implement p2p application on Android.
My application consists of a background service and several Android Activity.
I would like to know if there is something to manage the high-level communication between two phones (if yes what?) or do I implement the communication layer over sockets?
Can an Android Activity bind to a service on another phone?

Thx